# How to centralize buttons on android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-dialog

I'm having troubles to create a layout like [that](http://cdn.gottabemobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Defaults.png), the Dialog on left side of image. But I want to create it using horizontal orientation. I want that my layout have this [appearance](http://blog.laptopmag.com/wpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/complete-action-i.jpg), but only with two buttons horizontally.

My problem is the layout xml file, I don't know how to start this layout...    =(

The real problem is how to edit the xml file to the buttons get centralized, I tried a lot of thinks, padding, orientation, align etc... But I cant align that. My current layout is [that](http://www.zimagez.com/zimage/capturadetela-11-02-2015-223440.php). How can I centralize the buttons?

Can someone help me?

And here is my xml file code...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
/>
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to create your desired layout with the buttons that you mentioned (I figured you can do this yourself). Then, you would use that layout to inflate an `AlertDialog` as I have done below:

```
View alertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.your_custom_layout,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.alertViewLayout));

new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle(title)
        .setView(alertView)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int which) {
                        // handle click here

                        // dismiss AlertDialog
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
        .setNegativeButton("No",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int which) {
                        // handle click here

                        // dismiss AlertDialog
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).show();
```

You could access the views in the `AlertDialog`'s layout by referencing the parent view (`alertView`);

```
ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton) alertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
ImageButton button2 = (ImageButton) alertView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
```

**Edit**

This is a sample layout file with 2 `ImageButtons` placed side-by-side.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/alertViewLayout"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:background="@+drawable/imageButton1"
        android:text="Button 1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:background="@+drawable/imageButton2"
        android:text="Button 2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit 2**

Since you want your buttons to have custom backgrounds, I suggest you use an `ImageButton` and set the `background` property to your choice background.

If you want more details on how to create a layout file, you can check [Android Developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html).

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I really apreciate your help... sorry for my bad explanation, but my problem is the layout. I'm newbie on android layout and I have no Idea of how to create the layout. Can you help me?

Comment: the buttons continues not centralized...

See here: http://www.zimagez.com/zimage/capturadetela-11-02-2015-230215.php

Comment: @Caaarlos I updated my answer again. Consider centering the parent layout.

Comment: Same problem @iRuth... How can I centralize the parent layout  programmatically?

Comment: Did you add `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` to your parent layout's tag like I did?

Comment: @Caaarlos I updated my answer again with `android:gravity="center"`.

Comment: Hi, your reply is giving me the same visual of @user3029091, but it is almost what I want. Look at the visual I want, it appers to be two layouts inside one parent layout and each button of these layout are centralized... Can you help me to make a layout like on the above screenshot?

Visual that i want: http://www.zimagez.com/zimage/capturadetela-12-02-2015-073558.php

Current visual: http://www.zimagez.com/zimage/capturadetela-12-02-2015-073949.php

Thanks for helping me!!

Answer (score 1):

you can do somethnig like this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button1"
            android:id="@+id/button1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button2"
            android:id="@+id/button2" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, your reply is giving me the same visual of @IRuth, but it is almost what I want. Look at the visual I want, it appers to be two layouts inside one parent layout and each button of these layout are centralized... Can you help me to make a layout like on the above screenshot?

Visual that i want: http://www.zimagez.com/zimage/capturadetela-12-02-2015-073558.php

Current visual: http://www.zimagez.com/zimage/capturadetela-12-02-2015-073949.php

Thanks for helping me!!

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more clear in your question please? I don't know if I got it right but I will try to explain it.

First, if you want to create a **custom layout** for you dialog, you should create a .xml file and then inflate it with this specific layout.

But I think that is not your case, what you want to do it's to simply create a custom dialog, right? The screen orientation doesn't matter (I don't know if you meant it).

I don't think I should explain you the whole process or just paste the code, it's better to you to get used with android official documentation, so take a look at this link: [Dialogs | Android Development](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Hope it can help you.

Comment: @Grabriel R., I edited my answer, I really sorry for my bad explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation = "horizontal">

 <Button
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:text="Large Text"
 android:id="@+id/textView6"
 />

 <Button
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:text="Large Text"
 android:id="@+id/textView7"/>

</LinearLayout>
```